# How to Load data as write on textbox like auto complet load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

My problem is I want idea or description about how to display records on webpage as I write in a text box. For example I have list of employees that shown to users. Now as user write "a" in text box suddenly display all the employees start with "a" then if I write "ab", suddenly display all records start with "ab". I can do it with postback by autopostback. But i want it like auto load as there is autocomplet textbox without any load instantly. May be any jquery about which I don't have any idea so please help me.

[Here is my webpage i want as i type "ri" only riya sharma should be display on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQXmM.png)

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkNC5.png)

Comment: How much volume of data do you think is the list of employees ?? I can suggest you a approach depending upon the volume of data.

Comment: Around 10 to 15 records

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a autocomplete textbox/input area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724741/making-a-autocomplete-textbox-input-area)

Comment: This feature is known as "one-way data binding".  If you're not committed to using JQuery, (and certainly on future projects) I recommend a framework like Angular or library like React that does data binding out of the box.

Comment: Are you still searching a solution for this problem? I can provide a solution if so..

Comment: Yes i still finding the solution. I want to do it with jquery also but don't know how to do it. As i am just about start learning asp .net and jquery.

Comment: Even if there is another solution then please suggest me...

Comment: Ok i finally get my problem name its problem of live search. now please help me how to solve it in asp .net